# Comparing outputs in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi guys i have an SSIS package and i want to compare the outputs from 2 data streams 
Essentially i want to compare the data coming from the ActivityCode stream with that from the eClaim Mapping stream to find out which records are missing or have changed in the eClaim Mapping.

The ActivityCode data is new data and the eClaim Mapping is data we have and may need updating.

Is there anyway to do this without storing the data back into a table?

I hope this is understandable

[image]

Comment: It's doable but could you describe how you'd determine what's new vs what has changed? Is there a business key or surrogate key we can use? How do you detect changes? Are deletes important? How much data are we talking about (thousands/lakhs/millions/billions) from each stream and how many columns are involved?

Comment: its a pain but the only way i can compare is on a string comparison...basically it links on a code and compares the names associated with those codes. Its about 40000 rows of data from each stream and only 2 columns Code and Mapped value. So i link on the Code field and want to compare the Mapped Value field for changes. I can do this with a lookup but was wondering if i could avoid writing to another table

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing another table, try the cache transform. You could then use look the lookup transform with the cached data.